# Can someone access my locally run website even if I haven't specified any port forwarding?

Tags: security, port, port-forwarding, localhost, xampp

I am using Xampp so I can test my web application directly on my own computer. I am concerned that someone can access my Xampp site since I am still connected to the internet. However, I have NOT explicitly enabled any port forwarding with respect to my Xampp site in my router firewall settings. Furthermore, I am using a dynamic IP address. Given the factors already stated, can someone from outside my local network still access my locally ran website?

Comment: You would need to specify what router to know for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can tell you that's not possible to acces from internet to your XAMPP setup.
First, if you don't use any dynamic dns service or give your IP address to anyone, it's difficult to know your current IP.
Second, if you didn't setup your router to forward the port(s) on which XAMPP is listening, the router didn't know to which computer forward the packets, so i rejects them.
For further security, you can setup a rule in your router firewall to reject packets sent from the net to yout XAMPP port(s). Every router has different setup, so you should refer to your router manual.

Comment: `if you don't use any dynamic dns service or give your IP address to anyone`   Port-scan/probe.     `Second, if you didn't setup your router to forward the port(s) on which XAMPP is listening, the router didn't know to which computer forward the packets`   Unless their particular, unspecified, router *does*.     `so i [sic] rejects them.`   Unless it doesn’t.

Answer (score 3):

If you are behind a router without port forwarding it will be not possible.

However, you can also configure XAMPP to run on 127.0.0.1 so that your are sure that even people from your inside network cannot access it.